# Add mime Content-ID to request payload (AJAX)

Tags: javascript, ajax, backbone.js, mime-types, multipartform-data

I need to add "`<message>`" as a Content-ID to my ajax request for my multipart form. I have a pretty simple request using Backbone's save:

```
var data = new FormData();
data.append('message', new Blob([JSON.stringify(message.attributes)],{type: "application/json"}),'message');
data.append(document.getElementById('fileInput').files[0].name,document.getElementById('fileInput').files[0]);
message.save({},{
    contentType: 'multipart/form-data',
    data: data
});
```

The first part of the form, "message," should have a Content-ID header. Any idea on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

As [`Backbone.Model.save`](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-save) uses [`$.ajax`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) to interact with server, you can set custom headers using `$.ajax`'s options.

**Using `headers` options:**

```
message.save({},{
    headers: {"Content-ID": "<message>" },
    contentType: 'multipart/form-data',
    data: data
});
```

**Using `beforeSend` callback of $.ajax:**

```
message.save({},{
    beforeSend: function(xhr) {
        xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-ID", "<message>");
    },
    contentType: 'multipart/form-data',
    data: data
});
```